# CSS ul.topnav li a:active

Tags: css

I am trying to set the current "active" link to white to show which page the user is on.
I see see on a previous post
"A link only takes up the a:active state when it is clicked, so you only see the change for a few seconds. You should look for a different way for getting it done, like adding a new css class for the selected menu item from your server side script. "
Q. How do I do this?

My CSS is:

```css
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a:link {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: larger;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav ul li.current a {
  color: Black;
}

/*
ul.topnav li a:visited {
 color: black;
}
*/
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: Aqua;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: none;
}
l.topnav li a:hover:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul.topnav li a:active {
  color: white;
  transition: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <!--<li><a class="active" href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>-->
  <li> <a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../Aboutus.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../new.html">NEW</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../Samples.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../catalog.html">CATALOG</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../search.html">SEARCH</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../distributors.html">DISTRIBUTORS</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../service.html">SERVICE</a></li>
  <li> <a href="../Mailto.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this information helps. Been trying to fix this for awhile now.

Regards,

Larry

Comment: `l.topnav li a:hover:active` must be `ul.topnav li a:hover:active`

Comment: @paxman, I have read your comments in the edit you tried to make to my answer (this should have been a comment, or an edit to your question). My answer suggests that you go through _every_ page and set the appropriate list item link to have the class of `active`. I can assure you the second part of my css will set the color to white if you have that class (assuming you have posted all of your css regarding the styling of these elements). When you say "I need it set back to black when not active as the only menu link in white should be the active one" are you referring to `.active` or `:active`

Comment: @paxman, how are you including the common menu file? what server technology is powering your site? (most have a way to identify the current page). As for the difference, `.active` refers to an element with a _class_ of "active". While [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) refers to the _event_ of "active". Have a read of the docs link to see when `:active` is natively triggered by the browser.

Comment: Hi haxxxton - I use Microsoft FrontPage editor. It's "include" function places a copy of nabar.html in each page where it is used, same as Dreamweaver's "Library" function. Don't know server technology, will try to find out. Do you have an idea on how to resolve the "only active link =white issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the html of your navigation to include an identifier for the "current"/"active" page. This would mean updating your `.html` pages to add something like `class="active"` to the link that represents the current page. You would then update your css to something like:

```
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: Aqua;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: none;
}

ul.topnav li a.active:hover,
ul.topnav li a.active {
    color: white;
    transition: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem of setting active links "white" and inactive ones "black using javascript. You can see the result here: http://www.nav-aids.com/new-navaids/index.html

My menu is setup as:

```html
   <div class="col-7 col-m-7">
          <ul class="topnav">
    <li> <a id="index"  href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li> <a id="about"  href="../Aboutus.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li> <a id="new1" href="../new.html">NEW</a></li>
    <li> <a id="products" href="../Samples.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li> <a id="catalog" href="../catalog.html">CATALOG</a></li>
    <li> <a id="search1" href="../search.html">SEARCH</a></li>
    <li> <a id="distributors" href="../distributors.html">DISTRIBUTORS</a></li>
    <li> <a id="service" href="../service.html">SERVICE</a></li>
    <li> <a id="contact" href="../Mailto.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-m-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>   
        </td>      
  </tr> 
</table> 
</div>

<!-- set active menu item to white, inactive to black --> 
<script language="JavaScript" type= "text/javascript">
 menuactive()
 </script>
```

My javascript is:

```js
/* set menu button to white when selected and black if not selected */
function menuactive() {

/* The javascript below returns the menu page name in sPath */
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
//var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

/* alert below used to verify which menu page selected */
/*alert(sPage);*/

if (sPage == "index.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("index");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else { 
 var x = document.getElementById("index");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "Aboutus.html") { 
 var x = document.getElementById("about");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else { 
 var x = document.getElementById("about");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "new.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("new1");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("new1");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "Samples.html") {
  var x = document.getElementById("products");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("products");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "catalog.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("catalog");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("catalog");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "search.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("search1");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("search1");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "distributors.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("distributors");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("distributors");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "service.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("service");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("service");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

if (sPage == "Mailto.html") {
 var x = document.getElementById("contact");
    x.style.color = "white";
} else {
 var x = document.getElementById("contact");
    x.style.color = "black";
}

}
/* End menuactive */
```

BUT - I have a problem. My css hover no longer works. CSS I am using is:

```css
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: Aqua;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: none;
}

ul.topnav li a.active:hover,
ul.topnav li a.active {
    color: white;
    transition: none;
}
```

Hovered links do not turn "Aqua". Any ideas?
Thanks.
Larry